# How to remove extra parameters in connecting web part?

Tags: web-part-connection

I have two web parts which are connected. In first web part I have dates and in second I am displaying relevant documents. It runs smooth when I just go through date one by one. But I am facing issue when there are more documents for a date. It shows me paging and if user click on paging it adds paging parameters to the URL. so when user click on next date second web part is empty. Is there any way we can remove these paging parameter when user click on next date?

Comment: Are these 2 web parts custom developed or are they out-of-the-box SharePoint web parts?

Comment: they are SharePoint list view web parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using java script for this issue. I checked the append parameters that were added while paging in document web part. It contains a parameter `#InplviewHash` after the first web part selection parameters. So on page load I removed the remaining URL and reloaded the page.

Here is my code sample.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentUrl = location.href;
//check if current url contains #InplviewHash
if (currentUrl.indexOf("#InplviewHash") != -1 && currentUrl.indexOf("CascDelWarnMessage")==-1){
window.location =currentUrl.substring(0,currentUrl.indexOf("#InplviewHash"));
}
});
```

I have put extra condition with `CascDelWarnMessage`, it is added in the URL when date web part uses the paging. So if it exists in URL, URL will not be changed.